# Specify memory limit in Racket

Tags: memory, racket, limit

In `DrRacket` I can set a memory limit using the GUI. However, I find the editor not sooo good and want to use another editor of my choice. But how do I specify the memory limit then?

I can think of two possibilities, but couldn't find anything about either of these:

- at the beginning of the code call some function to set the memory limit
- when invoking `racket` (not DrRacket GUI tool, but the REPL on command line) give it some arguments to specify the limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the beginning of the code, you can set a memory limit for the module. [(docs)](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/custodians.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._custodian-limit-memory%29%29)

```
#lang racket/base
(define MAX-BYTES 1000)
(custodian-limit-memory (current-custodian) MAX-BYTES)

....
```

I don't know a straightforward command-line solution, but you can call `custodian-limit-memory` in your [racketrc](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28idx._%28gentag._292._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29) file to set a limit for the REPL.

See also [racket/sandbox](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html), especially `call-with-limits`.

Comment: Both answers are great, however, I'll accept this one, because I like the define of max bytes. Very readable.

Answer (score 11):

See [custodians](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/custodians.html).

For example:

```
#lang racket

;; Set limit
(custodian-limit-memory
   (current-custodian) (* 2 1024 1024))

(define x (make-bytes (* 4 1024 1024)))
```

Result of this code is 'out of memory'.